# Parse Cloud Code curl webservice return unauthorized error

Tags: javascript, web-services, parse-platform

I use Parse Cloud code to build my own webservice. however all of the sudden one day , I call my webservice using curl , I just get  {"error":"unauthorized"} error message. The Keys havent been changed. just all of the sudden, one day , I got this message when I debug.

does somebody know why? how can I fix it?

Comment: Erm, I'm sure you can ask their support if you are _certain_ you didn't change anything yourself. Note that keys can expire, what is the validity of yours?

Comment: I didn't see my keys are expired. and I did ask their support , but they dont answer it. and I create a new app using the same code it works  . but I am afraid, some days the problem come back again. all of the sudden,  cant call the webservice.

Comment: FWIW, I was also getting "error" "unauthorized"; i just had to wait a bit for the right settings to percolate, like 10 minutes.

Comment: it seems to me that they change the key, check all your keys carefully

Comment: were you able to find out the cause of this issue? i just saw it happening with me out of the blue!!

Comment: well, i just saw that Parse's CloudCode is down… so thats probably why I'm seeing this error!!

Comment: Check your keys carefully. they change the key all of the sudden. last time i have this problem, because of the key change without update me